# JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database

Tags: coldfusion, sybase, coldfusion-9, sap-ase

I have problem with my ColdFusion application. When I try to log into my account it generates the following error

```
JZ0SJ: Metadata accessor information was not found on this database.
Please install the required tables as mentioned in the jConnect documentation.
```

I am using SQL Anywhere 9 and also jConnect-6_0. Can anyone help me with this please.

Comment: Did you _install the required tables as mentioned in the jConnect documentation_?

Comment: Hi,No I did not install any talbes mentioned in jConnect...but why my other application and database works well without installing any tables in jConnect..can  you please give me some links on this tables.and how do i install this tables.?Thanks

Comment: I don't know how to install the jConnect...

Comment: I hope someon will come herea and help me...Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It seems no one ever properly answered this. 
Just in case it comes in handy (though I'd never recommend using this database), 
to solve the above problem, install the metadata tables. Run the following statement being the only account connected to the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE Upgrade JCONNECT ON
```

As mentioned in the [Sybase documentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1530/doc/html/san1281564736871.html).

Comment: I have read-only access to a database controlled by a vendor and am connecting using SQL Workbench.  Is there a way of connecting without running that SQL Statement?